# ClassLoader sometimes fails to load resource

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, classloader

For 2 tests in a unit test class I need a report file. I try to load it as followed:

```
private File getTestFile() {
        try {
            return new File(URLDecoder.decode(ClassLoader.class.getResource("/reports/report.xlsx")
                .getPath(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I run these tests for the first time, the following happens:

- First test: the classloader finds the resource and returns the file, the test passes.
- second test: the classloader doesn't find the resource and returns null, the test fails.

After this, both tests continue to fail until I rebuild the project then the first test passes and the second fails again.

The report.xlsx is located at `src/test/resources/reports/reports.xlsx`.

Is there something I do wrong or that explains this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason for your problem, but it seems strange that you use `ClassLoader.class.getResource(...)` for loading the resource. This will look up the resource in the system classpath. Instead you should use either `getClass().getResource(...)` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)`!

Another reason: Your test code somewhere deletes the file. This explains why the second test cannot find it any more, and why also the first test fails when you run the test again.
But as IDEs like eclipse always copy all resource files from the src to the bin directory when building the project, the file gets restored every time you rebuild your project. That's why the first test can load the file once after a rebuild.

Comment: I tried both solutions but none of them help me, I just get the same result.

Comment: @Tom Then maybe your problem is somewhere else. Is it possible that your code somewhere deletes the file?

Comment: Indeed, in my code I delete the file (because it's temporary thet I fetch from the database). Never thought about the fact it would also delete my original (test) file. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've changed the answer to also reflect the real reason of your problem.